# How to unset specific array in nested foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, unset

I have an output array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => null
            [count] => 0
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [Dagadu Bocah] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Dagadu Bocah
                            [count] => 47
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [HirukPikuk] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => HirukPikuk
                                            [count] => 5
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [DGD] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [item] => DGD
                                                            [count] => 1
                                                            [child] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [DGD] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => DGD
                                            [count] => 5
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Malioboroman] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [item] => Malioboroman
                                                            [count] => 1
                                                            [child] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [Malioboroman] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => Malioboroman
                                            [count] => 2
                                            [child] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )
                )
         )
   )
```

in my expectations I can use the loop as I asked earlier in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745120/how-to-unset-every-array-in-nested-foreach) by doing repetitions in such a way as to delete certain arrays to eliminate different parts of the array which is an array that is above the array which has three items namely 'item', 'count' and 'child' and how to produce arrays like this from the array above?

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => null
            [count] => 0
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Dagadu Bocah
                            [count] => 47
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => HirukPikuk
                                            [count] => 5
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [item] => DGD
                                                            [count] => 1
                                                            [child] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => DGD
                                            [count] => 5
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Malioboroman] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [item] => Malioboroman
                                                            [count] => 1
                                                            [child] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item] => Malioboroman
                                            [count] => 2
                                            [child] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )
                )
         )
   )
```

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: If you use a recursive function with a reference parameter for the array, when you get to the level that you want to unset, it will affect the original array.

Comment: wait, I edit my question

Comment: You seem to make phrases without end. Can you split your paragraph in shorter phrases so we can understand better what you are asking?

Comment: Also, please don't post output of `print_r`, but post your input and expected output in PHP syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to convert the `child` arrays from associative arrays to indexed arrays.

Assuming your data is called `$data`, here is a recursive function you could use:

```
function convert(&$data) {
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        if(isset($row["child"])) {
            $row["child"] = array_values($row["child"]);
            convert($row["child"]);
        }
    }
}

// call it for each row
foreach($data as $row) convert($row);
```